# Non-entangled non-classical quantum correlations?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Are there any list or classification of non-entangled quantum correlations in quantum states for multiparty (possible high dimensional) quantum states (included infinite-dimensional case)? I mean, a list of classification of non-classical quantum correlations like those of quantum discord and quantum dissonance. Are there more beyond those? Are they exclusive of 2-partite systems or can be defined por n-partite systems?

**References**

1. About Quantum Discord: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep06956
2. About some non-classical correlations: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219749914500373

Comment: If you have (non-zero) correlations between the states of two (or more) quantum systems then aren't the systems by definition entangled ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Well, for one thing, there is discord.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch And Quantum dissonance, they are one of the reasons of my question...

Comment: I'm afraid to say your question is rather unspecific -- it would help if you could generally clarify it, and make more clear what you are after (and what would constitute a good answer). Let me add that I never heard of quantum dissonance, so a reference might be helpful.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch For instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1572

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5417 seems a better reference.